# Why C++ inheritance not allow base class's public member inherit to derived class's private member?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I wondering something about inheritance.

```
class Base{
   public:
     virtual int f(){return 0;}
};
class Derived:public Base{
   private:
     virtual int f(){return 100000;}
};
int g(Base & b){
     return b.f();
}
int main(void){
     Base b;
     cout << "g(b) = " << g(b) << endl;
     Derived d;
     cout << "g(d) = " << g(d) << endl;
```

}

I have 2 class one is Base class that have virtual function f and the other is Derived class that have inheritance from Base class. But Derived class has virtual function f that is private member function.
The problem is that in Base class virtual function f is public member, but in derived class virtual function f is private member.
And when I execute this program the result is

```
g(b) = 0
g(d) = 100000
```

I think this implies that the value Base & b(In function g) can control Derived private member. So this is not allow to use.
So I wondering why we shold not redefine public member in Base class to private member in Derived class?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Simple, it does not make sense.

Comment: When public method should be private in derived class is not trivial question form design point of view.

Comment: Maybe not.  I'll delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I wondering why we shold not redefine public member in Base class to private member in Derived class?

There is no technical reason to ban tightening of access specifier of an override of a public virtual member function of public parent. The language allows it.  A program that does so is well formed, and its behaviour is well defined. However, there is also very rarely a practical reason to ever do such a thing, because the member of the parent is still accessible and the virtual dispatch reaches the private override as you have demonstrated.

Other languages have made different decisions on this matter. For example, Java does not allow an override to tighten the access modifier.

Comment: Re "no practical reason", well it's used in the ATL library, for example, in combination with a little dirty trick, to restrict access to reference count functions. IIRC.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf fair enough. I couldn't imagine a good reason to do it, but I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 1):

C++ lets you make the override `public`, `protected` or `private`. but regardless it will override the `public` base-class function and can be called via that interface.  That gives the C++ programmer extra control...

With the override `private` you can't call `d.f()` directly, which could help prevent accidental/inappropriate use.

### Example of utility of private override

```
struct TCP_Client
{
    virtual void disconnect();
    ...other things...
};

struct FTP_Client : TCP_Client
{
    void quit();
    ...other things...
  private:
    void disconnect() override;
};
```

The above reflects a design in which a `FTP_Client` *is a* `TCP_Client`, so the `TCP_Client` interface is conveniently publicly inherited - that means you could perhaps get stats the `TCP_Client` collects or later adds, like say # byte sent/recv-ed.  But, by making `disconnect()` `private` you encourage users to call `quit()`, which would send a proper "QUIT" message to the server before calling `disconnect()`.  You could make `disconnect()` send `QUIT`, but say the server's unresponsive and you decide to `disconnect()` at the TCP level - after explicitly casting to `TCP_Client&` to make it clear you're knowingly doing so - why bother sending `QUIT`: the output stream buffer may be full and your app unable to enqueue more data....